# Why is a BroadcastIntent not fired immediately

Tags: xamarin.android

My Xamarin C# Android program targeting Android 8.1 has a lock screen Notification.  It has a button with a PendingIntent.GetBroadcast action.

When I run this on an Android 6.0 phone, and I press the button while my app is visible onscreen, it fires immediately.

When I turn off the screen and back on (but don't unlock it), and my Activity has been Stopped, pressing the button doesn't raise the intent in my app for a few seconds. Android Device Monitor shows that it gets the intent but then waits until it calls my app:

```
09:39:52.531: V/ActivityManager(949): Broadcast: Intent { act=mybutton flg=0x10000010 cmp=MyApp.Android/md564336ff3eaa53a44a463178bbe2012c2.LockScreenBroadcastReceiver bnds=[722,1028][866,1220] } ordered=false userid=0 callerApp=null
....
09:39:59.422: I/mono-stdout(17592): INFO:20181012 09:39:59.42 Create LockScreenBroadcastReceiver
```

In this instance there was about 7 seconds before the BroadcastReceiver object in my app was created and called.

Running on an Android 8.1 phone there is no delay, but I'm not sure if that's because of the phone, or Android version.

I've tried creating the notification both with notificationManager.Notify and via a Service with StartForeground(id, notification). Both behave the same.

Comment: Try to use  <intent-filter android:priority="2000"> . And set the value of  priority large than 1000

Comment: Thanks Lucas, I'll try that next time it happens. I rebooted the phone and now it's working as expected.